# Force Final Cut to use embedded timecode in preference to file creation time?

Tags: final-cut-pro, timecode

I have a series of clips from a GoPro that have embedded timecodes -- the media start/end fields show up correctly in the Info inspector.  However, when the files were copied between filesystems, the file creation times were not preserved, and the creation times are not in the same order as the timecodes.

Unfortunately, when I try to make a multicam clip, the clips are ordered by creation time instead of by timecode, even though I am specifying timecode for angle assembly.  Is there any way to force FCPX to ignore file creation time entirely and go with the timecode?